# Moving two sprites with the same name at the same time

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, sprite

I'm trying to move both a rocket and word attached on the sprite to move up at the same time. However, I've set it such that only the words fly up and not the rocket. I was thinking of renaming rocket (used for words) to something else, but I feel like that would be a terribly inefficient way. Here's what I have so far

```
- (id)init
{
    // Apple recommend assigning self with supers return value
    self = [super init];
    if (!self) return(nil);

    // Enable touch handling on scene node
    self.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

    //Add a sprite
    rocket[0] = [CCSprite spriteWithImageNamed:@"rocket_base_blue.png"];
    rocket[0].scale = (0.15f);
    rocket[0].positionType = CCPositionTypeNormalized;
    rocket[0].position  = ccp(0.5f,0.23f);

    rocket[1] = [CCSprite spriteWithImageNamed:@"rocket_base_red.png"];
    rocket[1].scale = (0.15f);
    rocket[1].positionType = CCPositionTypeNormalized;
    rocket[1].position  = ccp(0.7f,0.23f);

    rocket[2] = [CCSprite spriteWithImageNamed:@"rocket_base_green.png"];
    rocket[2].scale = (0.15f);
    rocket[2].positionType = CCPositionTypeNormalized;
    rocket[2].position  = ccp(0.9f,0.23f);

    [self addChild:rocket[0]];
    [self addChild:rocket[1]];
    [self addChild:rocket[2]];
    [self setupWordRockets:2];
    [self intro];

    // done
    return self;
}

// -----------------------------------------------------------------------
#pragma mark - Game Events
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------

- (void)setupWordRockets:(int) wordLength
{

    //randomizes the words
    NSInteger rando = arc4random() % 2;
    if (rando == 1) {
    // Add a sprite
    rocket[0] = [CCSprite spriteWithImageNamed:@"b.png"];
    rocket[0].scale = (0.16f);
    rocket[0].positionType = CCPositionTypeNormalized;
    rocket[0].position  = ccp(0.5f,0.2f);
    rocket[1] = [CCSprite spriteWithImageNamed:@"a.png"];
    rocket[1].scale = (.16f);
    rocket[1].positionType = CCPositionTypeNormalized;
    rocket[1].position  = ccp(0.7f,0.2f);
    rocket[2] = [CCSprite spriteWithImageNamed:@"g.png"];
    rocket[2].scale = (.16f);
    rocket[2].positionType = CCPositionTypeNormalized;
    rocket[2].position  = ccp(0.9f,0.2f);
    } else {
    rocket[0] = [CCSprite spriteWithImageNamed:@"g.png"];
    rocket[0].scale = (0.16f);
    rocket[0].positionType = CCPositionTypeNormalized;
    rocket[0].position  = ccp(0.5f,0.2f);
    rocket[1] = [CCSprite spriteWithImageNamed:@"a.png"];
    rocket[1].scale = (.16f);
    rocket[1].positionType = CCPositionTypeNormalized;
    rocket[1].position  = ccp(0.7f,0.2f);
    rocket[2] = [CCSprite spriteWithImageNamed:@"p.png"];
    rocket[2].scale = (.16f);
    rocket[2].positionType = CCPositionTypeNormalized;
    rocket[2].position  = ccp(0.9f,0.2f);
    }
    [self addChild:rocket[0]];
    [self addChild:rocket[1]];
    [self addChild:rocket[2]];

}

- (void)launchRocket
{
    CCActionMoveTo *actionMove = [CCActionMoveTo actionWithDuration:1.0f position:ccp(0.5f, 0.9f)];
    [rocket[0] runAction:actionMove];
    CCActionMoveTo *actionMove2 = [CCActionMoveTo actionWithDuration:1.0f position:ccp(0.5f, 0.9f)];
    [rocket[1] runAction:actionMove2];
    CCActionMoveTo *actionMove3 = [CCActionMoveTo actionWithDuration:1.0f position:ccp(0.5f, 0.9f)];
    [rocket[2] runAction:actionMove3];
    [self scheduleOnce:@selector(explode:) delay:1];
}
```

I'm also wondering if there's also a more efficient way in randomizing the words because I feel like this is the brute force method, or at least a more tedious way of doing this. Any feedback would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Thats because when setupWordRockets function works, you store words in rocket array and when you call launchRocket, it moves the words.

You should separate those and use 2 arrays (one for words one for rocket sprites), so you can give proper actions to rockets as well.

Comment: I know, but is it possible to combine them both with the same name?

Comment: I am not sure I understand your purpose. If you just want to control them over one object, why don't you create a Rocket class?